# Rails Routing - Action Being Handled as an ID in Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to set a custom route (`fun` in the example below), but my `controller#action` keeps getting read as an `id` in my params.

My `routes.rb` file reads:

```
api.namespace :v2 do |v2|
    v2.resources :apps,    :only => [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
    v2.connect "/apps/fun", :controller => :apps, :action => :fun, :format => 'json', :conditions => {:method => :get}
end
```

My logs read:

```
Processing Api::V5::AppsController#show (for 10.0.0.2 at 2022-04-28 19:40:13) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"fun"}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was a conflict with the `resources` line above, changing the type of the request to `POST` caused this to work.

Comment: order of the routes matters. just put `connect` above `resources`